# GOlang core dump analysis using delve throws error 'unrecognized core format'

Tags: go, delve

Iam trying to analyse core file of GO program generated by gcore using delve. Below are steps I have followed. I got Unrecognized format error

```
$go version
go version go1.13.1 darwin/amd64
$/Users/sudhakar/go/bin/dlv version
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.4.0
Build: 37bee98a8821843314b561bc6ab328dfff2aad1b
$./hello &
[1] 72335
$gcore 72335
$sudo gcore 72335
$/Users/sudhakar/go/bin/dlv core ./hello /cores/hello-72335-20200427T185443Z 
unrecognized core format
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of this post darwin/amd64 is not supported by delve.

Ref: https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/usage/dlv_core.md

However this can change over time (delve may add support to this arch) [image]attaching screenshot of documentation (at the time of this post)

*Special thanks to delve-dev list member (Choudhary Sourya Vastayan) who pointed me to this.*